# How can I catch all the incoming gRPC messages in Java?

Tags: java, grpc

For example, you can receive bidirectional streaming incoming messages with the following code.

```
public class DataService extends DataServiceGrpc.DataServiceImplBase {
    @Override
    public StreamObserver<DataReq> send(StreamObserver<DataResp> responseObserver) {
        return new StreamObserver<DataReq>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(DataReq value) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And say I have some other classes like this to catch each in-coming gRPC messages.

If I want to capture and control all the in-coming messages before these classes receive them, what is the standard way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StreamObserver` is part of the stub, so no. But you can make a `ServerInterceptor` and register it with `serverBuilder.intercept()`. The interceptor can see every incoming message by wrapping the ServerCall.Listener.

```java
class MyInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT,RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT,RespT> next)
    return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<>(next.startCall(call, headers)) {
      @Override public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
        // your code here

        super.onMessage(message); // call into the application
      }
    };
  }
}
```

`next` would end up being another interceptor or the application. The generated code (e.g., `DataServiceImplBase`) implements `ServerCallHandler` and has it call the application (e.g., `DataService.send()`). So this interceptor can run before the application runs.